# rails6 app: minitest failing with ActionView::Template::Error: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest, ruby-on-rails-6.1

A bit of a puzzler - I've got an app using a very simple gem I wrote (UIAvatars) to generate a URL to an Avatar API. This demonstrably working in my Development rails app (the Avatar is displayed with no issues) but when I try to run my controller tests it causes errors like so:

```
Error:
InitiativesControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
ActionView::Template::Error: uninitialized constant ProfilesHelper::UIAvatars
    app/helpers/profiles_helper.rb:17:in `profile_image_link_for'
    app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:62
    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:23
    test/controllers/initiatives_controller_test.rb:15:in \`block in <class:InitiativesControllerTest>'
```

The method in profiles_helper is:

```
  def profile_image_link_for(profile, **options)

    image_tag(
      UIAvatars.generateURL(name: profile.full_name, size: "128", background: "random"), 
      options
      ).html_safe

  end
```

bundle says it is installed:

```
% bundle info ui_avatars
  * ui_avatars (0.0.1)
    Summary: Generate avatars with initials from names using https://ui-avatars.com
    Homepage: https://rubygems.org/gems/ui_avatars
    Path: /Users/thatsme/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/ui_avatars-0.0.1
```

it's in my Gemfile in the default group

```
gem 'ui_avatars'
```

Any idea what could be causing this problem?

Comment: I don't know, that's weird. I don't know how to reproduce your error. Maybe your test command (e.g. `rake test`) is actually running another version of ruby, and therefore doesn't have all gem dependencies installed? -- You could try prepending it with `bundle exec`, to be sure.

Comment: You could also try adding `require 'ui_avatars'` to the top of the file, although this *shouldn't* be necessary.

Comment: Or maybe you're using some sort of preboot (e.g. `zeus`) that's causing issues with your test environment? You may need to restart the prebooter, if you have one, to pick up new library dependencies.

Comment: Okay well done @TomLord - I'd tried upgrading to ruby 2.6.7 per security advice but it won't compile on macOS; and so I've had 2.6.7 in my .ruby-version file whereas I was still actually using 2.6.6. Fixing my .ruby-version file has solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Answer is that `.ruby-version` had a different version of ruby (2.6.7) than I was actually using (2.6.6) and so ruby could not find the gem installed in the expected path when running minitest.

(why it still worked in rails is a question for another day).